# jQuery - Text and Image scrolling effects are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, text, scroll

http://honghanhdinh.com/

I am currently developing my website and I am running into some troubles with some of the parallax tutorials I am learning.

As you can see, the plane and the words to my name "Hong" appears on on the opening page but the other 2 parts of my name "Hanh Dinh" only appears when beginning to scroll down. In addition, the plane also disappears upon scrolling and flys out from the right to the left.

I don't want the plane to appear upon entering the website but for it to naturally slide out to the left when scrolling down. I also want my full name "Hong Hanh Dinh" to appear upon entering the website--not just the Hong part.

I've tried many things to fix it but I think I'm missing something.

Here is the beginning of HTML code:

```
  <BODY>

  <!--Begin about info--!>

  <MAIN>

  <section id="bg" data-speed="10" data-type="background">
  <div id="plane">
  <img src="http://www.locanto.info/classifieds/images/airplane.png">
  </div>


  <div id="parallax2">
  <h2 id="center" class="parallax2">Hong</h2>
  <h2 id="left" class="parallax2">Hanh</h2>
  <h2 id="right" class="parallax2">Dinh</h2>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
  #bg {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-size
  }

  #parallax2 {
  height: 800px;
  margin-bottom: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 200px;
  }

  /* Parallax Scrolling text */

  #center.parallax2 {
  font-size: 175px;
  color: #CC3333;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-align: center;
  left: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
  }


  #left.parallax2 {
  color: #336699;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  left: 400px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  }


  #right.parallax2 {
  color: #C5C3DE;
  font-size: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  bottom: -300px;
  }
```

This is the jQuery for the "Hong Hanh Dinh" scrolling:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var controller = $.superscrollorama();
  controller.addTween(
    '#parallax2', 
    (new TimelineLite()).append([
    TweenMax.fromTo($('#left.parallax2'), 1, {
    css: {
        top: 200
    },
    immediateRender: true
  }, {
    css: {
        top: -900
    }
  }),
    TweenMax.fromTo($('#right.parallax2'), 1, {
    css: {
        top: 500
    },
    immediateRender: true
  }, {
    css: {
        top: -1800
    }
  })
    ]), 1000 // scroll duration of tween
  );

  });
```

This is the jQuery for the flying plane:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
  $('#plane').css({
    'width': $(this).scrollTop(),
    'height': $(this).scrollTop()
  });
  });
  });
```

Please let me know if my error is in the CSS or in the jQuery. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could fix this by adding width: 0; and overflow: hidden; to your div#plane. Otherwise, follow these steps:

Step 1:
Remove the img tag from the plane div, it is not needed. Add the id to the img tag itself.

```
<img id="plane" src="http://www.locanto.info/classifieds/images/airplane.png">
```

Step 2:

```
#plane{
    position: fixed;
    right: -WIDTH OF IMAGE;
}
```

Step 3:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#plane').css({
            'right': $(this).scrollTop() - WIDTH OF IMAGE,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This completely fix the plane problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your name "Hanh Dinh" does exist when it loads but it is out of our range of sight, change this line:

```
 css: {
        top: 200
    }
```

To a number like -400 and you'll see it'll appear on screen.
(That is for Hanh, for Dinh you'll need a larger number like -900.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped it positioned in the correct place upon entering the site.

However, there is another problem now. The whole text 'Hong Hanh Dinh' immediately jumps upwards upon scrolling. I was trying to figure out what part of the code affects this. Do you think I should try modifying the CSS or the jQuery code in order to prevent this hiccup?